# How to select all commits from somebody on one branch and insert into another branch?

Tags: git

There are two branches:

master: there's no commits from userA

branchA: there are some commits from userA, also some trash commits from other users

Now I need to insert all commits from userA on branchA into master(preserve date).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a quick one liner to do this.
First filter the commits on `branchA` by author, get their commit id and then cherry-pick them on master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log branchA --author='userA' | awk '/commit/ {print $2}' | while read commit; do git cherry-pick $commit; done
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cherry-pick is what you need.

Merging a specific commit from one branch to another is pretty easy: use the
 `git cherry-pick`
 command.

The syntax is:

`git cherry-pick <commit hash>`.

Here is how you go about doing it.

First make a note of the commit hash using the `git reflog` or `git log` command.

Then, switch to the branch where you'd like to merge the commit and run `git cherry-pick` **with the commit hash**, as shown in the example below.

`$ git cherry-pick d4d8e7c`

Now you will have merged the specific commit from one branch to the other.